# combine strings with cycles

Tags: python, string, python-itertools

I want to combine string like below in python 2.7.11
input:

```
s1=['aapl','msft']
s2=['us']
s3=['bs','pl','cf']
```

desired output:

```
s0=['aaplusbs','aapluspl','aapluscf','msftusbs','msftuspl','msftuscf']
```

i have tried using itertools and itertools.cycle for the purpose. here is the latest piece of code that come close but still does not gives me desired output.

```
in>> ' '.join('%s%s%s' % i for i in zip(s1,itertools.cycle(s2),itertools.cycle(s3))).split()
out>> ['aaplusbs', 'msftuspl']
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `itertools.product(s1, s2, s3)` instead

Answer (score 0):

@Siraj, you will need to do a bit extra stuffs to get exactly what you want on top of itertools.product(s1,s2,s3) as below.

```
import itertools

s1=['aapl','msft']
s2=['us']
s3=['bs','pl','cf']

ss = itertools.product(s1,s2,s3)
for s in ss:
    print(' '.join(s).replace(" ",""))
```

yielding outputs as below:

```
aaplusbs
aapluspl
aapluscf
msftusbs
msftuspl
msftuscf
```

For those who wants to know more about itertools like me, here goes reference, https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Why did you do `' '.join(s).replace(" ","")`? Why not simply `''.join(s)`?

Comment: vaultah, itertools.product returns tuple and if you do join(s) only it will have a space in between like. `aapl us bs
aapl us pl
aapl us cf
msft us bs
msft us pl
msft us cf
`

Comment: Run `for s in ss:print(''.join(s))`. There're no extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

this what i can do

```
    >>> s1=['aapl','msft']
    >>> s2=['us']
    >>> s3=['bs','pl','cf']
    >>> s0=[]
    >>> 
    >>> for i in s1:
            for j in s2:
                for k in s3:
                    print i+j+k
                    s0.append(i+j+k)


    aaplusbs
    aapluspl
    aapluscf
    msftusbs
    msftuspl
    msftuscf
    >>> s0
    ['aaplusbs', 'aapluspl', 'aapluscf', 'msftusbs', 'msftuspl', 'msftuscf']
    >>>
```